# Android Studio update corrupted gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

So I downloaded a .zip from the latest 2.0 version (here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-0) because Android Studio didn't allow me to download a patch and automatically update itself.
And then pasted the .zip folder tree into my installation directory.

Now I have this gradle error:

```
Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionExecuter.withCancellationToken(Lorg/gradle/tooling/CancellationToken;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/BuildActionExecuter;
```

Please tell me there's a way to fix this without reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be careful and close Android Studio ==>

- go to :

  ```
  android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib
  ```
- move all jar files starting with `gradle*`  to other folder in your desktop per example ==> remove them from lib folder
- Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.

**update:**

*from @alex-newman (first comment):*

There were 2 versions of gradle* inside: android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.10. I deleted the 2.8 leftovers and it got fixed.

Comment: All right I found the problem. There were 2 versions of `gradle*` inside: `android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.10`. I deleted the 2.8 leftovers and it got fixed. Thanks!

Comment: But now the Run button is grayed out. Any idea? The gradle build works fine except I can't Run the app. EDIT: switched from release to debug and works.

Comment: from Menu  `Run` do you have `Run 'android'`?